# How to handle a map argument in a nodejs C++ module

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I have a C++ module for nodejs. I need to accept a key/value pair as argument for a method.

var my_map = {'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2'};

Not sure what to do after this:

```
void MyClient::AcceptData(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    if (args.Length() != 1)
    {
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,
            "Usage: Key/Value Map")));
        return;
    }
// It returns true for args[0]->isObject(), but not for args[0]->IsMap()

// Now what? How do I get a C++ map out of args[0] ?
// What do I cast it into?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer...

```
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = args[0]->ToObject();
v8::Local<v8::Array> props = obj->GetPropertyNames();
std::map<std::string, std::string> theMap;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < props->Length(); i++)
{
    char key[1000], value[1000];
    props->Get(i)->ToString()->WriteUtf8(key, 1000);
    obj->Get(props->Get(i))->ToString()->WriteUtf8(value, 1000);
    theMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is a Map object, you can retrieve it through this code:

```
Handle<Map> map = Handle<Map>::cast(args[0]);
```

And then use the properties and attributes of the map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The javascript code is this: var my_map = {'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2'}; 
Is that a map object? It fails IsMap(), but returns true for IsObject().